# What is a 'first enemy' called?

Tags: single-word-requests

We have "best friends" and "close friends", because you give first importance to them. Like that, what should I call an enemy who is first enemy? I.e. you want to hurt him most then the rest of your enemies. What should we call them?

Comment: Best Friend antonym is Worst Enemy.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archfoe), an **archenemy**, **archfoe**, **archvillain**, or **nemesis** is the principal enemy of someone or something. In vernacular English, archenemy and nemesis are the two from the four above that are actually used commonly.

There's no single English word to describe **the** single most important enemy in which case you need to combine two words:

- Primary Adversary
- Main Opponent
- Sole Archenemy or Sole Nemesis

Note to the OP:  While archenemy has no friendly connotation, nemesis can also be used to refer to friendly rivalry.

Comment: Not a criticism but note that all of these, apart from the last, sound rather superhero-comic. I doubt you'd refer to an "archenemy" or "archfoe" of some historical king, for example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Agree, the two primary words used commonly in vernacular are archenemy and nemesis.

Comment: arch-rival is also used a lot in newspapers, an etymological note on nemesis too; the word started as the ancient Greek for a spirit of divine retribution - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemesis_(mythology)

Comment: There's also **archnemesis**.

Answer (score 21):

The idiomatic opposite of *Best Friend* is *Worst Enemy*.

Comment: I would say to not use this, because "worst enemy" is ambiguous. Is your worst enemy the enemy that is _worst for you_, or _worst at being an enemy_.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat, Idiomatically, it means the former, and is never used as the latter except maybe as a joke.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat It's not ambiguous at all. The person who is worst at being my enemy is my best friend and, if I wanted to talk about that person, I'd say "best friend". Therefore, it's reasonable to infer that, when anybody other than Amelia Bedelia says "worst enemy", they mean their archnemesis.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Counterexample: Person1: "Did you see [movie]? [badguy] really sucked!" Person2: "Yeah, [badguy] is like, the worst enemy ever!"

Comment: @Benubird OK, though that's not unambiguous either: it clearly means "[badguy] isn't good at being an enemy." What I should have said is that, when anybody other than Amelia Bedelia says "my worst enemy", they mean their archnemesis.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, that makes more sense then. I think the distinction between "my worst enemy" and "the worst enemy" is worth making, as it really changes the possible interpretations.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat "Worst enemy" is no more ambiguous than "best friend." Is your best friend the friend that is best for you, or best at being a friend? This is a red herring anyway. Both terms are subject to the speaker's feelings about them. One hates his worst enemy the most and loves his best friend the most. The terms really have nothing to do with the actual quality of friend or enemy that someone is.

Comment: @fredsbend but a best friend is _both_ "the friend that is best for you," _and_ "best at being a friend." A worst enemy obviously cannot be both.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat You missed the point they they are subjective terms. Plenty of people claim someone who is not really a good friend as their "best friend" and things lesser than what is actually the worst for them as their "worst enemy."

Comment: +1: using any of the other answers would make you sound like a comic-book character.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably referring to an [arch-enemy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archenemy) (archenemy):

> - a principal enemy

Examples of arch-enemy:

> - The two politicians were archenemies.
> - The country went to war with its archenemy.

Source:http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archenemy

Comment: yea arch-enemy is what i needed

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could use *sworn enemy* per CALD:

> [sworn enemy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/sworn-enemy): Sworn enemies are people who will always hate each other.

Comment: yea that sounds good.